# How can i retry after catch?

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs

How can i retry after catch ?

I want to retry my observable after catch method automatically without calling another subscribe. How can i do that ?

I have something like this for now:

```
intercept(observable: Observable<Response>): Observable<Response> {
        return observable.catch((err, source) => {                
                return this.refreshToken()
                    .flatMap(res => {
                        if (res.status === 200) {
                            return observable;
                        }
                        return Observable.throw(new Error('Can\'t refresh the token'));
                    });
        });
    }
```

So when i have my observable and call `subscribe` on it it will catch error `->` refresh token `->` and then return observable where i have to call another subscribe. I dont want to do that. how can i make it work with that subscribe before ?

The call example will looke something like this:

```
let request = this.http.request(url);
intercept(request).subscribe(res => { //do something });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a couple of operators which can be used in conjunction with catch to handle retrial/repetition. They are useful operators, they allow you to conditionally resubscribe to observables which have terminated. From the official documentation for `retryWhen` :

> Repeats the source observable sequence on error when the notifier
>   emits a next value. If the source observable errors and the notifier
>   completes, it will complete the source sequence.

Additional info here :

- [retryWhen](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/error_handling/retrywhen.html),
- [repeatWhen](http://blog.danlew.net/2016/01/25/rxjavas-repeatwhen-and-retrywhen-explained/)

You can find some examples here from previous questions:

- [Using `retryWhen` in http requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39189111/using-retrywhen-in-http-requests)
- [How to retry only on certain error emitted by the source observable in RxJs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29135235/how-to-retry-only-on-certain-error-emitted-by-the-source-observable-in-rxjs)
- [How to build an rx poller that waits some interval AFTER the previous ajax promise resolves?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35856397/how-to-build-an-rx-poller-that-waits-some-interval-after-the-previous-ajax-promi/35878692#35878692)

From the second SO question :

```
src.retryWhen(function (errors) {
    // retry for some errors, end the stream with an error for others
    return errors.do(function (e) {
        if (!canRetry(e)) {
            throw e;
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Could you please show some of the examples? The links may be gone tomorrow. :)

Comment: The examples are in the SO links (last three links). When they are gone, it means SO is gone

Comment: I really just meant your first two links. If you think this question is a duplicate, then mark it so, otherwise don't just post links. :P

Comment: Is there a way i can update request header? Becouse it does repeat with the same header